# Typescript literal types used as key to indexer

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to define a typescript literal type which can be used as a string key in an indexer?

```
type TColorKey = 'dark' | 'light';

interface ColorMap {
    [period: TColorKey]: Color;
}
```

This throws the error: `An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.`

Comment: You can use an enum?

Comment: @Amy No, you can only assign numeric constants to enums, not strings. That's why string literal types exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible thanks to a new feature called [Mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12114). Just make sure you're using nightly version of typescript compiler (`typescript@next`) because it's not in stable build yet (at the time I'm writing this).

```
type TColorKey = "dark" | "light";

type TColorMap = { [P in TColorKey]: Color };
```

Comment: One more observation for VS Code

If you want the editor to use `typescript@next` language specification (so that it doesn't throw errors):
1) Run `npm install -g typescript@next`
2) Add `"typescript.tsdk": "yourGlobalNpmPath/node_modules/typescript/lib"` to `settings.json`

Comment: In case you are wondering why you don't get TSC errors when using a key that is not part of your literal type: You need to set `noImplicitAny: true` in your `tsconfig.json` file.